# Wordpress FAQ Schema Markup Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, json, wordpress, markup

[There are 2 examples on Google Search Central.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/faqpage)
I don't know much about javascript or JSON-LD so I have put the second code (Micro Data) on the bottom of my Wordpress template file (HTML).

```
<html itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
<head>
    </head>
<body>
  <h1>
    Frequently Asked Questions(FAQ)
  </h1>
  <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
    <h2 itemprop="name">What is the return policy?</h2>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
      <div itemprop="text">
        Most unopened items in new condition and returned within <b>90 days</b> will receive a refund or exchange. Some items have a modified return policy noted on the receipt or packing slip. Items that are opened or damaged or do not have a receipt may be denied a refund or exchange. Items purchased online or in-store may be returned to any store.
        <br /><p>Online purchases may be returned via a major parcel carrier. <a href="http://example.com/returns"> Click here </a> to initiate a return.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
    <h2 itemprop="name">How long does it take to process a refund?</h2>
    <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
      <div itemprop="text">
        We will reimburse you for returned items in the same way you paid for them. For example, any amounts deducted from a gift card will be credited back to a gift card. For returns by mail, once we receive your return, we will process it within 4–5 business days. It may take up to 7 days after we process the return to reflect in your account, depending on your financial institution's processing time.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
  <h2 itemprop="name">What is the policy for late/non-delivery of items ordered online?</h2>
  <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
    <div itemprop="text">
      Our local teams work diligently to make sure that your order arrives on time, within our normal delivery hours of 9AM to 8PM in the recipient's time zone. During  busy holiday periods like Christmas, Valentine's and Mother's Day, we may extend our delivery hours before 9AM and after 8PM to ensure that all gifts are delivered on time. If for any reason your gift does not arrive on time, our dedicated Customer Service agents will do everything they can to help successfully resolve your issue.
      <br/> <p><a href="https://example.com/orders/">Click here</a> to complete the form with your order-related question(s).</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
  <h2 itemprop="name">When will my credit card be charged?</h2>
  <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
    <div itemprop="text">
      We'll attempt to securely charge your credit card at the point of purchase online. If there's a problem, you'll be notified on the spot and prompted to use another card. Once we receive verification of sufficient funds, your payment will be completed and transferred securely to us. Your account will be charged in 24 to 48 hours.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div itemscope itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
  <h2 itemprop="name">Will I be charged sales tax for online orders?</h2>
  <div itemscope itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
    <div itemprop="text">
      Local and State sales tax will be collected if your recipient's mailing address is in:
      <ul>
        <li>Arizona</li>
        <li>California</li>
        <li>Colorado</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I checked my post url in [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), it said there was no FAQ markup detected. Of course, the  tags and contents showed up 'cause they are HTML. 
As far as I know, JavaScript doesn't show contents visually to readers. **Then, should I use both codes (JSON-LD + Micro Data) inside of my template file?** Also, if it is needed, can I put JavaSript codes bottom of my template file? Sadly, there isn't much explanation how to use the code. Here is JSON-LD code from Google Search Central.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example Site - Frequently Asked Questions(FAQ)</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [{
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "What is the return policy?",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "<p>Most unopened items in new condition and returned within <b>90 days</b> will receive a refund or exchange. Some items have a modified return policy noted on the receipt or packing slip. Items that are opened or damaged or do not have a receipt may be denied a refund or exchange. Items purchased online or in-store may be returned to any store.</p><p>Online purchases may be returned via a major parcel carrier. <a href=http://example.com/returns> Click here </a> to initiate a return.</p>"
        }
      }, {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "How long does it take to process a refund?",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "We will reimburse you for returned items in the same way you paid for them. For example, any amounts deducted from a gift card will be credited back to a gift card. For returns by mail, once we receive your return, we will process it within 4–5 business days. It may take up to 7 days after we process the return to reflect in your account, depending on your financial institution's processing time."
        }
      }, {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "What is the policy for late/non-delivery of items ordered online?",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "<p>Our local teams work diligently to make sure that your order arrives on time, within our normaldelivery hours of 9AM to 8PM in the recipient's time zone. During  busy holiday periods like Christmas, Valentine's and Mother's Day, we may extend our delivery hours before 9AM and after 8PM to ensure that all gifts are delivered on time. If for any reason your gift does not arrive on time, our dedicated Customer Service agents will do everything they can to help successfully resolve your issue.</p><p><a href=https://example.com/orders/>Click here</a> to complete the form with your order-related question(s).</p>"
        }
      }, {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "When will my credit card be charged?",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": "We'll attempt to securely charge your credit card at the point of purchase online. If there's a problem, you'll be notified on the spot and prompted to use another card. Once we receive verification of sufficient funds, your payment will be completed and transferred securely to us. Your account will be charged in 24 to 48 hours."
        }
      }, {
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": "Will I be charged sales tax for online orders?",
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text":"Local and State sales tax will be collected if your recipient's mailing address is in: <ul><li>Arizona</li><li>California</li><li>Colorado</li></ul>"}
        }]
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking myself and answering myself haha. It worked! **If you want to use FAQ schema markup, you need to write your own schema codes based on the [Google Search Central](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/faqpage) examples and put the codes into your template file.** You can also put JavaScript codes below the HTML codes. 
 I hope someone who has similar question would be helped and save his/her time!